# Retrieving data LINQ vs Reflection

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I was hoping someone could tell me which is the more efficient and/or correct way to retrieve some data.

I have some XML files coming from a 3rd party and their attached DTDs.  So I've converted the DTD into a C# Class so I can deserialize the XML into the classes.  I now need to map that data to match the way my data structures are set up.

The question ultimately is; should I use reflection or LINQ. The format of the XML is somewhat generic by design, where things are held in Items [Array] or Item [Object].

I've done the following:

```
TheirClass class = theirMessage.Items.Where(n=> n.GetType() == typeof(TheirClass)).First() as TheirClass;

MyObject.Param1 = ConversionHelperClass.Convert(class.Obj1);
MyObject.Param2 = ConversionHelperClass.Convert(class.Obj2);
```

I can also do some stuff with Reflection where I pass in the names of the Classes and Attributes I'm trying to snag.

Trying to do things the right way here.

Comment: Linq queries if written effectively can be as fast as reflection. I found this article which give good information on this.. http://stefan.rusek.org/Posts/LINQ-Expressions-as-Fast-Reflection-Invoke/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general rule I'd suggest avoiding reflection unless it is absolutely necessary! It introduces a performance overhead AND means that you miss out on all of the lovely compile time checks that the compiler team have worked so hard to give us.

Linq to entities essentially queries against an in memory data set, so it can be very fast.

If your ultimate goal is to parse information from an xml document, I'd suggest checking out the [XDocument class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx). It provides a very nice abstraction for querying xml documents.

Comment: Is reflection more expensive?  Is it just a general rule of thumb?

Comment: Reflection is VERY expensive. Avoid it if you can.

Comment: Thanks. I remembered years ago someone telling me to avoid it like the plague but I didn't know why.